# Open link when Keystroke CTRL + T is pressed Javascript, Repl.it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to Open A link when I do the Keystroke Assignment CTRL + T but I cant figure out how. can someone please help me in full description with examples. I am also using the Coding platform Repl.it

Comment: As a general rule on StackOverflow, you'll want to ask a more specific question. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info. I will however give you a nudge in the right direction. You'll want to use `document.addEventListener()` with `keydown` as the event, and you can use `shiftKey` on the `KeyboardEvent` object your callback gets. Check out MDN for more info on those bits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can override `Ctrl` + `T`, it's a native shortcut to open a new tab in browsers.

The code below will add a shortcut for `Ctrl` + `A`.

```js
const addPressKeyShortcutListener = (keysOrder, callback) => {
  let pressedKeys = [];

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    const isAlreadyTracked = pressedKeys.includes(event.key);
    if (isAlreadyTracked) {
      return;
    }

    pressedKeys.push(event.key);
    console.log('Pressed', pressedKeys.join(' + '));

    const isShortcutPressed = keysOrder.join(' + ') === pressedKeys.join(' + ');
    if (isShortcutPressed) {
      callback();
    }
  }

  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    const lastPressed = pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length - 1];

    const shouldRemoveOnlyLast = lastPressed === event.key;
    if (shouldRemoveOnlyLast) {
      pressedKeys.pop();
      console.log('Pressed', pressedKeys.join(' + '));

      return;
    }

    pressedKeys = [];
    console.log('Pressed', pressedKeys.join(' + '));
  }


  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

  const removePressKeyShortcutListener = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
  }

  return {
    removePressKeyShortcutListener,
  }
};

addPressKeyShortcutListener(['Control', 'a'], () => console.info('Ctrl + a clicked!'));
```

To remove the shorcut we can use `removePressKeyShortcutListener`.

```
const {
    removePressKeyShortcutListener,
} = addPressKeyShortcutListener(['Control', 'a'], () => console.log('Ctrl + a clicked!'));

removePressKeyShortcutListener();
```